# Using telnet command in script for send mail

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

I wanna send an email via a command in Centos7. I used 'telnet' command for this issue like this:

```
I touch example.sh file and save these command inside it :
echo "open mail.test.com 25"
sleep 3
echo "mail from:sender@test.com"
echo "rcpt to:receiver@test.com"
echo "data"
echo "hello"
echo "."
sleep 3
```

and use this command `./example.sh | telnet`
but it dosn't work

could you please help me 
thanks

Comment: Why not use an actual command-line-based email program like [sendmail(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sendmail/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`telnet`is designed for interactive usage. Use `netcat`, `ncat`, `nc`, `socat` or any other tool of this family.

Example:

```
./example.sh | ncat mail.test.com 25
```

Herefore you have to edit your script:

```
echo "mail from:sender@test.com"
echo "rcpt to:receiver@test.com"
echo "data"
echo "hello"
echo "."
sleep 3
```

The last `sleep 3` is important to give `ncat` enough time to handle result.

btw, I have tested nothing (just written down)

Comment: when i run       './example.sh | ncat mail.test.com 25 '  i face to this error: "554 SMTP synchronization error"

Comment: Then it is most likely a timing error (maybe: don't send answer before question). Use more `sleep`. But better is to use `socat` with redirection of stdin and stdout to the script. Read `man socat` for details.

Comment: I used more sleep time 40 seconds, it is working now. thank you

Comment: addition to short sleeps, when using telnet, we need to use `echo "QUIT"` to break the telnet connection after the completion